# Changing an image in a dialog box before showing it

Tags: java, android, image, drawable

I have an activity which consists of a GridView with multiple (different) images. When the user clicks on one image, a customized dialog box shows up in which an enlarged version of the image appears as well as some text below.

What I want accomplished: the image shown in the dialog box must correspond to the chosen image in the GridView. I thought that I could change the image resource in the onItemClick method, but the application crashes instead (only when I use the setImageResource command).

Here is the code:

```
public class Releases extends OptionsActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.releases);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ReleasesImgAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(Releases.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (position == 0)
                {                   
                    CustomizeDialog cdWCE = new CustomizeDialog(Releases.this, R.layout.releases_popup);
                    ImageView wce = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rlsImg);                                       
                    wce.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                    cdWCE.show();                   
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

releases.xml simply consists of a GridView.

I can't debug the program because my Eclipse debugging haven't been working for a while now.

Comment: Could you maybe provide a stack trace or at least tell us what exception you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try finding the `ImageView` in the actual dialog where you set the layout (e.g.

```
ImageView wce = (ImageView)cdWCE.findViewById(R.id.rlsImg);
```